# How can I stop Eclipse from continuously attempting to connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, windows-10, eclipse

I work behind a proxy, that needs authentication using a workplace-provided password. Proxy blocks the password after 3 failed attempts, and I have to request the Network Administration a new password. The password also only authenticates when I am punched in.

Eclipse keeps attempting to connect to the proxy even after a failed attempt. Sometimes I punch out for lunch and leave the machine locked. When I return from lunch, my password is blocked, because Eclipse kept trying to connect the whole hour.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to not keep retrying to connect after a single failed attempt?

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) and STS (3.9.3) , but this issue happens in Kepler and other versions of Eclipse too.

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to limit the attempts but why not just put in the username and password for the proxy?  Alternatively, if it's trying to check for updates, though mine only shows its looking for updates when Eclipse is started - what about disabling the automatic update check?  If either of these are an option for you, I could put it in an answer.

Comment: @JGlass i'm sorry. I am aware that I can remove the UN/PW in the settings, but that is something I would like to avoid having to do every time I need network. And removing auto update check is not a solution: it will still keep humping the network card if it decides to connect for other reasons.

Comment: ROFL "humping the network card" - you wouldnt think it would connect to internet unless it was for updates - possibly a plug-in is doing it like JBoss Developer tools does?  Looks like something like this [block internet connection on eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650713/block-internet-connection-on-eclipse) might be your only solution.